# How to create a clock model with any numbers in Mathematica?

Tags: graphics, labeling, image3d

[image]I wonder how to create a clock-model in Mathematica. I got this model image from a maths group, I am posting this for reference. I wish to create a clock model like this with any numbers. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Point+Circle+Table+Text. Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am new to Mathematica coding, please help me.

Comment: Take a look at mentioned symbols and `Graphics` and hit F1 for a start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are lazy like me, you may consider [`ClockGauge`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClockGauge.html):

```
SeedRandom[1]
labels = RandomInteger[50, 12]

labeling = AssociationThread[Range[12], labels]; 

ClockGauge[PlotTheme -> "Business", ImageSize -> Large, GaugeMarkers -> None, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[FontColor -> Cyan, FontSize -> Scaled[.075]]] /. 
 Text[t_Integer, a___] :> Text[labeling @t, a]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

If you need a more/less serious look/feel consider

```
ClockGauge[PlotTheme -> "Scientific", ImageSize -> Large, 
  GaugeMarkers -> None,  GaugeLabels -> None, LabelStyle -> FontSize -> Scaled[.075]] /. 
 Text[t_Integer, a___] :> Text[labeling @ t, a]
```

[image]

```
ClockGauge[PlotTheme -> "Marketing", ImageSize -> Large, 
  GaugeMarkers -> None, LabelStyle -> FontSize -> Scaled[.075]] /. 
 Text[t_Integer, a___] :> Text[labeling @ t, a]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
clock[radius_?NumericQ, innerFraction_?NumericQ, labels_?ListQ, fontStyles_?ListQ] := 
 Block[{points = RotationTransform[π - π/Length[labels]][
                  CirclePoints[Length@labels]*innerFraction]},
  Graphics[{
    Thick,
    Circle[{0, 0}, radius],
    MapThread[
     Style[Text[ToString[#1], #2], Sequence[fontStyles]] &,
     {Reverse@labels, points}],
    Disk[{0, 0}, radius/30]
  }]]

(* create a clock with some prime numbers *)
clock[1, 0.8, Prime /@ Range[12],
  {FontFamily -> "Courier", FontSize -> 18, FontWeight -> Bold}]
```

[image: clock]

Comment: This is very useful, thanks much.